# How to call external JavaScript function from Thymeleaf template

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have myScript.js in a Gradle project in /static/js/myScript.js. In HTML Thymeleaf template I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/myExternalScript.js}"></script>
...
<input id="myBtn" type="button" th:onclick="myExternalFunc();" value="Submit" />
```

When I run the server I get:

> Could not parse as expression: "myExternalFunc();"

It works fine when the script is inline, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
th:onclick="'myExternalFunc();'"
```

or

```
th:onclick="'javascript:myExternalFunc();'"
```

Comment: In the given example the right solution would be do not use thymeleaf at all, instead, just write regular JS handler `onclick="myExternalFunc();"`. Much cleaner.

Comment: I will need to add a model from controller later, that is why th